# Move an element in the DOM based on containing link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to move the `<li>` elements with a `focusassortment` link on the DOM with the `.appendTo()` function.

Is it possible to do this based on the link? Or maybe give the `<li>` elements that contain the correct link a CSS class based on the link to target? I can't use first-child since its position is dynamic.

```
<ul class="tabmenu" id="tabmenu">
 <li onclick="location.href='/m4n?seid=etailer-focusassortment'" cacheno="753781029"><a id="link0" name="link0" href="/m4n?seid=etailer-focusassortment">Uw producten</a></li>
 <li onclick="location.href='/m4n?seid=etailer-orderhistorylist'" cacheno="686783597"><a id="link1" name="link1" href="/m4n?seid=etailer-orderhistorylist">Mijn account</a></li>
 <li onclick="location.href='/m4n?oid=362_'" cacheno="1572880"><a id="link2" name="link2" href="/m4n?oid=362_">Bottom</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: based on containing link? what and where to move? It's unclear what you're asking about.

Comment: Why do you have a link in `<li onclick="location.href=` while you already have the same link in the `<a href=` ?

Answer (score 2):

If I got you right what you need is [Contains Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

You can select that `li` by doing

```
$("ul.tabmenu li[onclick*='focusassortment']")
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/Ljsz36p2/1/

```
$('.tabmenu li').each(function(){
    var oc = $(this).attr('onclick');
    if(oc.match(/focusassortment/i)){
        $(this).addClass('black');
    }
});
```